# reCAPTCHA has ceased working since adding SSL Certificate

Tags: php, ssl, captcha, recaptcha

I have the latest version of reCAPTCHA. On the front end I am using the JS library

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

and using PHP to validate.

This was working fine yesterday but today it has ceased to work. The only change is the addition of an SSL Certificate to the site, so I am assuming its that.

The CAPTCHA box appears fine on the form and validates but the PHP script redirects the user to the error page and does not send the email.

My code for this is:

```
$captcha = null;
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
        $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

   }

$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=PRIVATE_KEY&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$response = json_decode($response);

if($response->success === false){
        header( "Location: $error_page" );
        exit;
    }

  else{

    //SEND MAIL

  }
```

Would anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: `var_dump($response)` produces:

```
errorobject(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["success"]=> bool(false) ["error-codes"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(22) "missing-input-response" } }
```

Comment: var_dump($response);

Comment: "missing-input-response" seems like a clear error to me. echo $captcha the post array etc

Comment: @Dagon any idea as to why this could be occuring? A google search reveals nothing

Comment: From https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify?hl=en `missing-input-secret` -> `The secret parameter is missing`. So it looks like your `?secret=PRIVATE_KEY...` is wrong

Comment: @Sean I dont think so. I've reset and changed it 3 times now.

Comment: its the `$captcha` echo it and everything else